# activerecord - ensure belongs_to points to a valid record when saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord

When saving a record with belongs to is it possible to ensure that the foreign key being saved in the child record actually exists in the parent table? (Assuming its not polymorphic).

I know there are plugins that can do this, but I'm wondering if ar has a means of handling this.

Thanks!

Comment: Why wouldn't you just let the db handle this with a foreign key?  Do you have a legacy database you cannot modify and so you are enforcing the referential integrity in the model?

Comment: @Wes: ActiveRecord doesn't understand FKs inside the database, you have to manage them by hand in migrations and manage them by hand when pulling down a copy of the database.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short I know AR doesn't handle referential integrity without you rolling your own with callbacks which is why I was asking why he was trying to handle it in AR.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `validates_presence_of`

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :model1

  validates_presence_of :model1
end
```

Comment: This ensures that a key is given but not that it actually exists in the parent table.

Comment: Note that I'm validating the presence of 'model1' the association, not 'model1_id' the attribute. I just tried this out on Rails 2.3.11 and it does in fact fail if you assign an id which doesn't exist in the associated table.

Comment: This works fine, in console and server.  The problem is with my tests.  Thanks for the input! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could do it by hand with [`before_save` and `before_create`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html) handlers. These aren't necessarily the best way but you shouldn't be afraid to roll up your sleeves and get the job done by hand when necessary.

And, because you're sensible (AKA paranoid), you could put a real foreign key constraint inside your database; an FK inside your database will also protect against corruption caused by deleting things that are referenced by other things. The downside is that ActiveRecord doesn't really support FKs in the database so you'd have to add and maintain them by hand with RAW SQL.

Comment: What do you mean by downside?  That ActiveRecord::Migration doesn't have a built in method to create or drop the FK constraint?

Comment: @Wes: Yes. Nor will AR pull down FKs (or check constraints) when you copy the database using AR. The FKs also won't appear in your `schema.rb` file. You can and should do it but you'll need to layer a bunch of processes and procedures on top of the usual AR way of doing things.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short Agreed that is a downside on schema.rb.  I only use AR to copy a database when I am dumping from one vendor and importing in a different vendor (ie sybase to mysql)

Comment: @Wes: You're kind of stuff with AR if you're using a shared database at Heroku. It is a shame that AR doesn't encourage known best practices.

Comment: @mu-is-too-short s/stuff/stuck :) This is why I don't use heroku :)

Comment: @Wes: Your sed-fu is weak today, you meant `s/stuff/stuck/` but close enough :) I don't want to be a sysadmin (too many panicked calls when I'm busy snowboarding and an hour away from a computer) and neither does anyone I want to work with, hence Heroku.